# Passing e.target.value is throwing me error

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, create-react-app

This is the error message that is showing when I run handleUserInputChange.

> index.js:1375 MissingMethodException: On_Off_Light.ChangeBrightness Due to: Attempted to access a missing member.

My function code:

```
  handleUserInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      brightness: e.target.value
    });
    this.unityContent.send("LightButton", "ChangeBrightness", e.target.value);
  };
```

This is howI am calling it:

```
onChange={this.props.handleUserInputChange.bind(this)}
```

As you can see, I have already bind this function, but when try to pass e.target.value as a parameter to

```
 this.unityContent.send("LightButton", "ChangeBrightness", e.target.value);
```

It keeps saying I am trying to access a missing member.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. It turns out that e.target.value returns a string value, which is not what I want. All I need to do is convert it to integer before I can pass it to my unity function.

```
handleUserInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      brightness: e.target.value
    });
    this.temp = parseInt(e.target.value)
    this.unityContent.send("LightButton", "ChangeBrightness",this.temp);
  };
```

I will leave it here for anyone who needs it in the future.